# How to change inner sep for nodes in nicematrix

Tags: nicematrix

With this example I want to create  table of variations of a function with `NiceArray` env. The  remaining problem is that the ends of the arrows are close to the values 0 at nodes `(2-2)` and `(2-4)` so I need to change `inner sep` value for these two nodes

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 5pt}

\begin{document}

$$\begin{NiceArray}[t]{|wc{1cm}|c!{\qquad}c!{\qquad}c|}
\hline
 x  & -\infty & 0 & +\infty \\
\hline
     & 0 &    & 0 \\
f(x) &   &    &   \\
     &   & -2 &   \\
\hline
\CodeAfter 
%\ShowCellNames
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\draw[->](2-2) -- (4-3);
\draw[->](4-3) -- (2-4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceArray}$$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These nodes are constructed with `inner sep =  0 pt` hard-coded in `nicematrix`.

You can, if you want, change the initial value of `outer sep` (see below). However, it's probably best practice to use the keys `shorten >` and `shorten <` of Tikz as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 5pt}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{NiceArray}[t]{|wc{1cm}|c!{\qquad}c!{\qquad}c|}
\hline
 x  & -\infty & 0 & +\infty \\
\hline
     & 0 &    & 0 \\
f(x) &   &    &   \\
     &   & -2 &   \\
\hline
\CodeAfter 
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\draw[shorten < = 1mm, ->](2-2) -- (4-3);
\draw[shorten < = 1mm, shorten > = 1mm, ->](4-3) -- (2-4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceArray}\]
```

As usual with `nicematrix`, you need several compilations.

[image: Output of the first code]

---

If you actually want to change the value of `outer sep` for all the nodes constructed (implicitly or explicitly) in your picture, here what you can do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 5pt}

\begin{document}

\[\tikzset{outer sep = 3mm}
\begin{NiceArray}[t]{|wc{1cm}|c!{\qquad}c!{\qquad}c|}
\hline
 x  & -\infty & 0 & +\infty \\
\hline
     & 0 &    & 0 \\
f(x) &   &    &   \\
     &   & -2 &   \\
\hline
\CodeAfter 
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\draw[->](2-2) -- (4-3);
\draw[->](4-3) -- (2-4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceArray}\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second above]

Comment: Thanks, how if I need to change `outer sep` only for 0 nodes `(2-2)` and `(2-4)`?

Comment: It's not possible to change `outer sep` for only some nodes...